# Assign a value to a shared variable?

Tags: vb.net, string, nullreferenceexception, shared, public

I need help assigning a value to a public shared variable i made.

```
Public Shared craftability As String = "Craftable"
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        craftability = "Non-Craftable"
    Else
        craftability = "Craftable"
    End If
```

When i try to use the value i assigned to it in another subclass it says:

*Variable 'craftability' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.*

and returns a null value.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in CheckBox1_CheckedChanged to see if craftability has really been assigned value. Also, make sure there is only one instance of craftability declared.

Comment: Use class name for accessing shared variables. `ClassWhereVariableDefined.craftability`.

Comment: Are you sure that its you want to declare a shared variable and not a static variable?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've declared a Shared variable outside  a class here. Shared variables are only used by instances of classes. For example if you want to track how many instances of a class there are, you would declare a shared variable within the class like this console app

```
Sub Main()
    Dim t1 As New testclass
    Dim t2 As New testclass
    Console.WriteLine(t2.Count)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Class testclass
    Private Shared instanceCount As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        instanceCount += 1
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Count
        Get
            Return instanceCount
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

What you end up with is **2** being written to the console. And the shared variable is only accessible by each instance of the TestClass.

OK Static variables are like local variables declared  in a procedure. However with regular local variables, when the procedure completes the local variable is destroyed. A static variable continues to exist and retains its most recent value. The next time you calls the same procedure, the static variable isn't declared again and reinitialized because it still exists and contains the latest value that you assigned to it. A static variable is only destroyed when the class or module that it was defined in is destroyed.

So your code should probably be

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
   Static Dim craftability As String = "Craftable"
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        craftability = "Non-Craftable"
    Else
        craftability = "Craftable"
    End If
```

However, looking at the code you've supplied, if you want **craftability** to be available throughout your class, then just declare it as you already have done - Outside a sub, but without the **shared** keyword. Without knowing how you want **craftability** to be used, I cant be more accurate I'm afraid. Hope this helps